# dotCover, Coded UI testsand the application under test

Tags: coded-ui-tests, dotcover

So we write functional test automation for our AUT in Coded UI. The development team uses dotCover to do unit test coverage analysis. I wonder if anyone knows if it is possible for Coded UI test cases to use dotCover to analyze the UI code in the AUT that is tested?

I readily confess that I know next to nothing about dotCover or coverage analysis. But it I were to learn that this was possible, I would learn more.

Thanks
S

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to cover coded UI tests via dotCover.

Comment: I was asking if it was possible to get coverage information of the Application Under Test (AUT) using dotCover and CodedUI for determining user interface code coverage>